# UncaughtExceptionHandler on Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I would like to do some custom logic anytime there is an uncaught exception in my application. Normally I would do something like:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myCustomHandler);
```

However, `Thread` is locked down on Google App Engine. The above code raises a security exception. Is there anyway to achieve similar functionality on Google App Engine?

EDIT: I have implemented my approach as a Servlet Filter. My experience with Java web programming is fairly limited. Can someone comment on such an approach? Since all requests in AppEngine originate as HTTP requests, I think this is a comprehensive solution.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        // Work my magic here...
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Servlets handle threads on their own so you should not mess with it in this way.

Instead, install a servlet [Error Handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Error_Handlers):

```
<error-page>
    <error-type>com.package.YourException</error-type>
    <location>/errors/handler</location>
</error-page>
```

then have `/errors/handler` map to servlet that handles the error and returns the appropriate response.

Comment: Interesting approach. Is there any benefit to using this over the approach I made in my edit (or vice versa)?